# Using FOP, is it possible to output info/warning on the command line?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I use the basic fop command in a cron. Under certain circumstances, for example when a value does not exists, I would like to print a warning on the standard output.

Ideally, I expect a special command like `<fox:stdout></fox:stdout>` which outputs nothing on the document but can be wrapped inside an `<xsl:if></xsl:if>` or something alike.

I could not find anything like that in the official documentation (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/), how would you do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xsl:message`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#message) to output messages.

Note though that how those messages are output can be different from one processor to the next.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you very much! As a side note: By default it outputs a warning in FOP, unless you specify `terminate="yes"`, in which case a warning is put out, then a severe exception.

Comment: @FabianPijcke: note that in all this FOP is not involved at all; `xsl:message` is handled by the XSLT processor. FOP just sees the FO elements generated by the XSLT.